# Why is it the case that multiple libraries aren't allowed from the same project in Cargo?

Tags: rust, web-component, rust-cargo, webassembly

Using `[[bin]]` in Cargo.toml allows me to compile multiple binaries from the same source of a Rust project.

But I want to deploy multiple web-components from the same source, and web-components are compiled as libraries. There is, however, no `[[lib]]`, only `[lib]` which allows only a single compile target.

I am new to Rust and Cargo so I don't yet fully understand every part of the ecosystem entirely, but I wonder how to go about building my multiple web-components without having a dozen small repositories?

---

If it matters, I plan to use the [webcomponent system of web-dom](https://github.com/web-dom/webcomponent) for this project, while I've used wasm-bindgen for another one with a similar setup (but only 2 components, so it wasn't much of an issue).

Comment: You don't have to have separate *repositories*, but you do have to have multiple Cargo projects.

Comment: you can have multi workspace, I think that should work in your case if I correctly understand what you want

Comment: @Shepmaster - it's not a duplicate. That question asks why there's only one [lib]. I don't particularily care about the why. I want to know how to set up my project with multiple web-components without having to duplicate everything inside.

Comment: @Stargateur can you elaborate on that? It might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tom just google it... https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section